# React - can't access passed function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a form where I use a component to display the rows so that the form page has n number of component pages.

```
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} loading={loading} >
  <table className="ui celled table" border="1">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th >Status</th>
        <th >Date </th>
        <th >ID</th>
        <th >Plan</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         {this.state.claims.map ( claim => <ClaimRow claim= { claim } updateClaims={this.updateClaims}  /> ) }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot className="full-width">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">
          <div className="ui small button">
            <Button Primary>Approve Selected</Button>
          </div>
          <div className="ui right floated button" >
              Next
                  <i class="right arrow icon"> </i>
          </div>
          <div className="ui right floated button" >
                  <i class="left arrow icon"></i>
             Prev
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  </form>
```

The page displays the ClaimRow's properly and each row has an OnChange event handler.  Inside the onChange event handler/row, I'd like to call updateClaims to set the State for the individual row in the parent Component.  This way, if someone clicks "approve", the parent component's state has all the changes ready to send to the DB.

When I click on "onChange", I am getting an error inside my onChange handler that it can't reference updateClaims.

"TypeError: _this.updateClaims is not a function"

My onChange handler

```
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({status: e.target.value} );
    this.updateClaims(this.state._id,this.state);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

`this.props.updateClaims(this.state._id,this.state)`

In the script,

`<ClaimRow claim= { claim }  updateClaims={this.updateClaims}  />`

`updateClaims` passed as a prop to `ClaimRow` component and it available on `props` within it.

To access it, in a class component, you need to to call it on `this.props`

Comment: about to say the same thing, where is this function defined, clearly in the parent, the child needs to call props (parent data)

Comment: Thx guys, I knew I was missing something simple.